# Getting value from div in jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I need help with Jest. I built a calculator for a take home challenge. I would like to check if adding two numbers returns the right output using jest.

I have this test where I am trying to grab the value from the calculator screen to see if it matches what I expect it to match (I console.logged just to figure out what was going on first):

```
  test('Can add, multiple, subtract and divide nums', () => {
    render(<App/>)
    const one = userEvent.click(screen.getByText(7, { selector: 'button' }));
    const add = userEvent.click(screen.getByText('+', { selector: 'button' }));
    const two = userEvent.click(screen.getByText(3, { selector: 'button' }));
    const equal = userEvent.click(screen.getByText('=', { selector: 'button' }));
    expect(screen.getAllByTestId('screen-id').innerHTML).toEqual(10);
  })
```

This is the screen component:

```
const Screen = ({ value }) => {
  return (
    <Textfit data-testid="screen-id" className="screen" mode="single" max={70}>
      {value}
    </Textfit>
  );
};
```

And this is where I render the component:

```
<Screen value={ calc.num ? calc.num : calc.res } />
```

What can I do to check what number currently appears on my screen

Comment: What happens currently? Give a [mre]. Why get _all_ if there's only one element with that test ID?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the test fails and returns undefined, I don't really get any errors and you're right, I don't have to find all

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I console.log `screen.getByTestId('screen-id').innerHTML` I get this     `Received: "<div style=\"display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;\">10</div>"`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a MRE that allows others to recreate the issue.